# How to scan QR code for WhatsApp Web?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, nexus-5, whatsapp-messenger, qr-code

I'm hoping this question is suited to this forum.
WhatsApp have just announced WhatsApp for the desktop browser ([https://web.whatsapp.com](https://web.whatsapp.com/)).

One of the steps is to scan a QR code using WhatsApp. I can't seem to find the option to scan the QR code.

The instructions say to open WhatsApp -> Menu -> WhatsApp Web.

The problem is that my menu doesn't have an option for WhatsApp Web.

My phone is a Nexus 5 on Lollipop 5.0.1.

Comment: I won't post this as an answer since it's only speculation: with the latest version, yesterday I rebooted my phone, but it still didn't appear. Today, when I checked it, it was suddenly there. The only thing that I could possibly think of is WiFi connection. I have a guess it will appear for the first time if you're connected to WiFi. However, I'm not sure if it's true or not.

Comment: That's a possibility. I wasn't on WiFi.

Comment: Contents of menu changes depending on the tab you have selected below. Choose `Chats` first, and only then tap menu…

Comment: I can't post an answer due to lack of reputation, but for me the WhatsApp Web option didn't appear until after I successfully "verified" my phone number.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

reboot your phone. I did that and the feature is there in the menu.

After rebooting, you may need to click on "chat," not on "calls" or "contacts." Hope that helps.

Comment: I just killed the app and it worked for me.

Comment: Thank you, this was solution: click on "chat," not on "calls" or "contacts."

Answer (score 3):

Update your WhatsApp to the latest version (2.11.498) and you will see the menu option `WhatsApp -> Menu -> WhatsApp Web`.

I have updated mine and am able to use WhatsApp web with the same menu option.

Comment: I had already updated to that version. I went to the Play store and there were no new updates for WhatsApp. I checked the About section in WhatsApp and it was the version number you mentioned.

Comment: @user1037894 are you connected to the WiFi? Is it still not shown?

Answer (score 0):

I completely re-installed WhatsApp and now I see the WhatsApp Web option.

Word of caution: I lost data when I uninstalled WhatsApp.